# progress bar value can't be set! in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, async-await, progress-bar, aws-sdk-net

i have an **async** upload task.Into that upload function :

```
 AddHandler fileTransferUtilityRequest.UploadProgressEvent,
                    Sub(sender As Object, e As UploadProgressArgs)
                        ProgressForm.CPBar1.Value = 0
                        Dim percent As Integer = convert.toint32(e.transferredbytes) 'e.transferredbytes as long 
                        myProgress = New Progress(Of Integer)(AddressOf ReportProgress)
                        myProgress.Report(percent)

                    End Sub
```

actually the `progressbar1.maximum=convert.toint32(sizeofupload)` and the `progressbar1.minimum=0` ofcourse, `sizeofupload` variable's type is `as long`

then about the`ReportProgress` is,

```
Public Sub ReportProgress(ByVal myInt As Integer)
        ProgressForm.CPBar1.Value = myInt
    End Sub
```

i have converted all long type values in int32 type. 
but,it does n't worked. the error shows value should be between maximum and minimum.!
 i want to progress the transferred bytes in my progress bar while uploading.`e.transferredbytes as long` variable 
had the transferredbytes value. so,can anyone knows what i'm missed?

Comment: First things first, what type is `fileTransferUtilityRequest` and is that event raised on the UI thread?

Comment: @jmcilhinney  => [Async, Await EventHandler return value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61833424/7444103)

Comment: Keep the ProgressForm.Maximum as `100` and remove `ProgressForm.CPBar1.Value = 0` from the Lambda. -- Since you know the file size beforehand (you're uploading it), divide the size by `100` and update the UI when you have uploaded a multiple of the calculated chunk. If you also want to show the number of bytes transferred, show this information in another control, a Label maybe. This: `myProgress = New Progress(Of Integer)(AddressOf ReportProgress)` is completely wrong. You don't add a handler each time you need to report progress, you do that just once, when you create a `Progress<T>` object.